# Is there a way to restrict access to Notes and Attachments while doing a global search

Tags: attachment, notes, global-search

Is there a way to restrict the search on notes and attachments for certain profiles?

If we type in doc or pdf in the global search then it shows all the notes and attatchments. There are so many attachments like like CV's which should not be available for certain profiles  . Is there a way to we can restrict these using profiles?

Or is there a way to hide the global search box itself?

Comment: If you disable chatter  you can disable the global search box but that is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, i dont want to do that. Is there a way to restrict notes and attachments for specific profiles?

Comment: one silly way may be to pin a bunch of items to the top, but that is by user account and would be painful for any admin to do. Still when the user looks for search all the notes and attachments are going to show up